# Bash script to execute git update

Tags: git, bash, github, terminal

I am attempting a bash script to run several git commands in sequence to update a repository. The command I concatenate at the end works if I manually input it into a terminal, but inside the bash script it doesn't do anything. What is the bash syntax error I am making?

```
cmd1="cd $myGitRepo"
cmd2="git add --all"
cmd3="git commit -m \"test commit msg\""
cmd4="git push"
cmd="$cmd1 && $cmd2 && $cmd3 && $cmd4"
echo "$cmd"
$cmd
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When faced with a problem like this, use the debug tools, such as the echo debugger, or the `-x` flag:

```
bash-3.2$ cmd="echo foo && echo bar"
bash-3.2$ $cmd
foo && echo bar
bash-3.2$
```

This shows that `&&` is not treated as syntax when it is the result of a shell variable.  Equivalently:

```
bash-3.2$ set -x
bash-3.2$ $cmd
+ echo foo '&&' echo bar
foo && echo bar
bash-3.2$
```

The `-x` flag tells the shell to print out each command, preceded by the `+` marker, before running it.

(You could get this treated as syntax by adding `eval` in front, but in general this is not a very good plan.)

Is there some reason not to just write the actual commands you want done, e.g.:

```
cd $myGitRepo && git add --all && git commit -m "test commit msg" && git push
```

as the body of your script?

If you want to automatically exit after a failing command, sh and bash both support `set -e`; bash gives this the additional name `errexit` (as a `-o` option).  So `set -e` tells the shell to exit immediately if any of the simple commands fail:

```
set -e
cd $myGitRepo
git add --all
git commit -m "test commit msg"
git push
```

(To end `-e` behavior, simply `set +e`.)